# Filtering Angular Google Maps Markers Using the $filter Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, filter

My goal is to figure out how to filter Angular Google Maps Markers using the $filter service.

Here's the backstory: 
I set up the google maps using the [angular-google-maps directive](http://angular-google-maps.org/#!/api).  However, I didn't set up the markers using the markers element directive from angular.  I set them up using the Google Maps JavaScript API (the traditional way).  So I used a hybrid approach to Google Maps.  (I feel this information is crucial.)

I am supposed to use the Module.filter() method and the $filter service in my main.js (controller).  I tried doing it.  However, I am stuck.  I am not sure what exactly goes inside the app.filter() method: should I recreate the map inside each filter function?  Moreover, I am not sure how to connect the changes from the $filter to the view.

Any help, even as comments, would be greatly appreciated.

Please explain the steps involved in the process.  I would appreciate as much detail as possible.

Here's my main.html (the Google Maps directive is at the very bottom):

```
    <div class="row height100">
        <div id="main-sidebar" class="col-md-2">
            <div id="main-container">
                <span id="main-header">TITLE</span>
                <br>
                <span id="main-subHeader">
                    SUBHEADER
                </span>
                <br><br>
                <span id="main-addInput" class="height100">
                    <!-- The 'options' & 'details' are ngAutoComplete attributes -->
                    <!-- 'details="details"' is where the lat/long information comes from -->
                    <input type="text" value="Enter Address" ng-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" options="options" details="details"/>
                </span>
                <br><br>
            </div>

            <div class="navigation" id="main-navList">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a target="_blank" href="#" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-mouseenter="type=true" ng-mouseleave="type=false">
                        <span class="fa fa-tasks crime-type"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="checkbox" id="murder-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'MURDER')" checked/>
            <label>Murder</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rape-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'RAPE')" checked/>
            <label>Rape</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="felonyassault-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'FELONY ASSAULT')" checked/>
            <label>Felony Assault</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="robbery-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'ROBBERY')" checked/>
            <label>Robbery</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="burglary-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'BURGLARY')" checked/>
            <label>Burglary</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="grandlarceny-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'GRAND LARCENY')" checked/>
            <label>Grand Larceny</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="gla-box" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(this,'GLA')" checked/>
            <label>Grand Larceny of Motor Vehicles</label>
        </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10 height100 no-padding">
            <google-map class="height100" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="map.options" control="mapControl">
            </google-map>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my main.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('crimespaceAngularApp');

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter){
    $http.get('/api/getCrimeData').success(function(crimeData){
        $scope.crimeMarkers = crimeData;
    });
    // Add map object to the $scope:
    $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 40.7127,
                longitude: -74.0059
            },
            zoom: 10,
            options: {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                styles: [{"elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ff4400"},{"saturation":-68},{"lightness":-4},{"gamma":0.72}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon"},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#0077ff"},{"gamma":3.1}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"hue":"#00ccff"},{"gamma":0.44},{"saturation":-33}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"hue":"#44ff00"},{"saturation":-23}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"hue":"#007fff"},{"gamma":0.77},{"saturation":65},{"lightness":99}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"gamma":0.11},{"weight":5.6},{"saturation":99},{"hue":"#0091ff"},{"lightness":-86}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":-48},{"hue":"#ff5e00"},{"gamma":1.2},{"saturation":-23}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"saturation":-64},{"hue":"#ff9100"},{"lightness":16},{"gamma":0.47},{"weight":2.7}]}]
            }
        };

    $scope.mapControl = {};

//--------------------------------------------------
    // Connect ngAutoComplete output to viewable map area:
    $scope.$watch('details', function(details) {
        $scope.map.center = {
            latitude: details.geometry.location.lat(),
            longitude: details.geometry.location.lng()
        };
        $scope.map.zoom = 16;
    });
//--------------------------------------------------
// CUSTOMIZING ICONS

 var circle ={
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: .9,
    scale: 6,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 1,
};

//--------------------------------------------------


    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    // var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    //             maxZoom: 16
    //         });

    // '$watch' registers a listener callback to be called whenever the watchExpression changes:
    $scope.$watch('mapControl', function(mapControl){
        var map = $scope.mapControl.getGMap();

        $http.get('/api/getCrimeData').success(function(crimeData){
            var markers =  _.map(crimeData, function(element){
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(element.latitude, element.longitude);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    title: element.type,
                    icon: circle
                });

                //---------------------------------------------
                // INFO WINDOWS:
                var infoContent = '<div style="width: 135px; height: 50px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Courier; color: black"><b>' + element.type + '<br>' + 'MONTH: ' + element.month + '<br>' + 'YEAR: ' + element.year +'<b></div>';

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, infoContent);

                //---------------------------------------------
                return marker;
            });

            // Need to add options to the following cluster constructor:
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                maxZoom: 16
            });
        }); // $http callback

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, infoContent){
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                infoWindow.setContent(infoContent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    }); // $scope.$watch('mapControl', )


}); // End of MainCtrl's scope ...

//--------------------------------------------------
// FILTER FUNCTIONS:

// #1: Filtering for Murders:

app.filter("murderFilter", function($http){
        var map = $scope.mapControl.getGMap();
        $http.get('/api/getCrimeData').success(function(crimeData){
        return function(){
                var murderMarkers =  _.map(crimeData, function(element){
                    if(element.type === "MURDER"){
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(element.latitude, element.longitude);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            title: element.type,
                            icon: circle
                        });

                        //---------------------------------------------
                        // INFO WINDOWS:
                        var infoContent = '<div style="width: 135px; height: 50px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Courier; color: black"><b>' + element.type + '<br>' + 'MONTH: ' + element.month + '<br>' + 'YEAR: ' + element.year +'<b></div>';

                        //---------------------------------------------
                        return marker;
                    }
                });
                    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, murderMarkers, {
                        maxZoom: 16
                    });
            };
    });
});
```